# Combine keyboard & consumer control in descriptor

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, bluetooth-gatt

I have a hid_discriptor which looks like this:

```
// from USB HID Specification 1.1, Appendix B.1
const uint8_t hid_descriptor_keyboard_boot_mode[] = {
    /*
       Keyboard
     */
    0x05, 0x01,                    // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x06,                    // Usage (Keyboard)
    0xa1, 0x01,                    // Collection (Application)

    0x85,  0x01,                   // Report ID 1

    // Modifier byte

    0x75, 0x01,                    //   Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x08,                    //   Report Count (8)
    0x05, 0x07,                    //   Usage Page (Key codes)
    0x19, 0xe0,                    //   Usage Minimum (Keyboard LeftControl)
    0x29, 0xe7,                    //   Usage Maxium (Keyboard Right GUI)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                    //   Logical Maximum (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                    //   Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    // Reserved byte

    0x75, 0x01,                    //   Report Size (1)
    0x95, 0x08,                    //   Report Count (8)
    0x81, 0x03,                    //   Input (Constant, Variable, Absolute)

    // LED report + padding

    0x95, 0x05,                    //   Report Count (5)
    0x75, 0x01,                    //   Report Size (1)
    0x05, 0x08,                    //   Usage Page (LEDs)
    0x19, 0x01,                    //   Usage Minimum (Num Lock)
    0x29, 0x05,                    //   Usage Maxium (Kana)
    0x91, 0x02,                    //   Output (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    0x95, 0x01,                    //   Report Count (1)
    0x75, 0x03,                    //   Report Size (3)
    0x91, 0x03,                    //   Output (Constant, Variable, Absolute)

    // Keycodes

    0x95, 0x06,                    //   Report Count (6)
    0x75, 0x08,                    //   Report Size (8)
    0x15, 0x00,                    //   Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0xff,                    //   Logical Maximum (1)
    0x05, 0x07,                    //   Usage Page (Key codes)
    0x19, 0x00,                    //   Usage Minimum (Reserved (no event indicated))
    0x29, 0xff,                    //   Usage Maxium (Reserved)
    0x81, 0x00,                    //   Input (Data, Array)
    0xc0,                          // End collection
};
```

Which works for keyboard codes;

However, i also would like to add consumer control to my sample, so i can also send volume up/down etc.

```
    /*
       Consumer Control
     */
    0x05, 0x0C,                     // Usage Page (Consumer Devices)
    0x09, 0x01,                     // Usage (Consumer Control)
    0xA1, 0x01,                     // Collection (Application)
    0x85, 0x02,                     //      Report ID
    0x75, 0x09, 0x01,               //      Report Size
    0x95, 0x09, 0x01,               //     Report Count
    0x15, 0x00,                     //      Logical Minimum (0)
    0x26, 0xFF, 0x07,               //      Logical Maximum (2047)
    0x19, 0x00,                     //      Usage Minimum (0)
    0x2A, 0xFF, 0x07,               //      Usage Maximum (2047)
    0x81, 0x00,                     //      Input (Data, Ary, Abs)
    0xC0,
```

The question is, that [in the provided demo code](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/example/hog_keyboard_demo.c); the code to send a report is this:

```
static void send_report(int modifier, int keycode){
    uint8_t report[] = { /* 0xa1, */ modifier, 0, 0, keycode, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
}
```

This works in terms of sending keystrokes; when i trace that call in the source code, it goes [to this function](https://github.com/bluekitchen/btstack/blob/master/src/ble/gatt-service/hids_device.c#L367);

```
void hids_device_send_input_report(hci_con_handle_t con_handle, const uint8_t * report, uint16_t report_len){
    hids_device_t * instance = hids_device_get_instance_for_con_handle(con_handle);
    if (!instance){
        log_error("no instance for handle 0x%02x", con_handle);
        return;
    }
    att_server_notify(con_handle, instance->hid_report_input_value_handle, report, report_len);
}
```

Which actually uses the `instance->hid_report_input_value_handle` instead of the hid_descriptor_keyboard_boot_mode; i also know why (in case people are wondering); [The spec mentions](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hid1_11.pdf);

> The HID Subclass 1 defines two descriptors for Boot Devices. Devices may
>   append additional data to these boot reports, but the first 8 bytes of keyboard reports and the first 3 bytes of mouse reports must conform to the format defined by the Boot Report descriptor in order for the data to be correctly interpreted by the BIOS.

...snip...

> When the HID class driver is loaded, it will issue a Change Protocol,
>   changing from the boot protocol to the report protocol after reading the boot interface’s Report descriptor.

So after the change protocol is called; the report is loaded into the `hid_report_input_value_handle`. So until now, everything is clear.

Then the main question comes; HOW do i send consumer control to my paired device? Is it just a matter of adding the reportId? e.g.

For keyboard keys as keydown event:

```
uint8_t report[] = { 0x01, modifier, 0, 0, keycode, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
```

And for consumer control (play/pause) as keydown event:

```
uint8_t report[] = { 0x02, 0xCD, 0x00};
hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
```

Is that about correct? Any guidance would be welcome, BLE is new to me hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

For the keyboard HID descriptor, given that it represents the following C structure:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Keyboard/Keypad Page inputReport 01 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x01 (1)
                                                     // Collection: CA:Keyboard
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardLeftControl : 1;       // Usage 0x000700E0: Keyboard Left Control, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardLeftShift : 1;         // Usage 0x000700E1: Keyboard Left Shift, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardLeftAlt : 1;           // Usage 0x000700E2: Keyboard Left Alt, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardLeftGui : 1;           // Usage 0x000700E3: Keyboard Left GUI, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardRightControl : 1;      // Usage 0x000700E4: Keyboard Right Control, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardRightShift : 1;        // Usage 0x000700E5: Keyboard Right Shift, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardRightAlt : 1;          // Usage 0x000700E6: Keyboard Right Alt, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  KB_KeyboardKeyboardRightGui : 1;          // Usage 0x000700E7: Keyboard Right GUI, Value = 0 to 1
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  : 1;                                      // Pad
  uint8_t  Keyboard[6];                              // Value = 0 to 255
} inputReport01_t;
```

...then I would expect the send function to look like:

```
uint8_t report[] = { 0x01, modifier, 0, keycode, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // <-- i.e. one less byte
hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
```

As for the Consumer Device report, the HID report descriptor seems quite wrong. It should be something like (assuming it is concatenated to your keyboard report descriptor):

```
/*
   Consumer Control
 */
0x05, 0x0C,                     // Usage Page (Consumer Devices)
0x09, 0x01,                     // Usage (Consumer Control)
0xA1, 0x01,                     // Collection (Application)
0x85, 0x02,                     //      Report ID
0x75, 0x10,                     //      Report Size (16)
0x95, 0x01,                     //     Report Count (1)
0x26, 0xFF, 0x07,               //      Logical Maximum (2047)
0x19, 0x00,                     //      Usage Minimum (0)
0x2A, 0xFF, 0x07,               //      Usage Maximum (2047)
0x81, 0x00,                     //      Input (Data, Ary, Abs)
0xC0,
```

...which represents the following C structure:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Decoded Application Collection
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
05 0C        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page 
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0001 Consumer Control (Application Collection)  
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000C0001: Page=Consumer Device Page, Usage=Consumer Control, Type=Application Collection)
85 02          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x02 (2)  
75 10          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field  
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
26 FF07        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x07FF (2047)  
19 00          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x000C0000 Unassigned  <-- Info: Consider replacing 19 00 with 18
2A FF07        (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x000C07FF 
81 00          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000000 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application 
*/
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Consumer Device Page inputReport 02 (Device --> Host)
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  reportId;                                 // Report ID = 0x02 (2)
                                                     // Collection: CA:ConsumerControl
  uint16_t ConsumerControl;                          // Value = 0 to 2047
} inputReport02_t;
```

...in which case, your function to send a Consumer Device request should work without modification:

```
uint8_t report[] = { 0x02, 0xCD, 0x00};
hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
```

...to send a Play/Pause request.

Don't forget to signal that "no keys are pressed" by following each send with (in the case of the keyboard):

```
uint8_t report[] = { 0x01, modifier, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // no keys pressed
hids_device_send_input_report(con_handle, report, sizeof(report));
```

This is the equivalent of a traditional "key up" notification.

Comment: If I get your intention correctly, you suggest to send a keyboard report to release consumer input, which is not the proper way to do it. In order to release consumer codes, you should send a consumer report with "Null" value. I.e. a value outside logical range (HID 5.10).